# Refer to parent of matched commit when using :/ syntax

Tags: git, git-rev-parse

The `:/` syntaxallows you to match commits using regular expressions. E.g., to create a fixup commit for an earlier commit that contains the string 'Add widget', you can write:

```
git commit --fixup ':/Add widget'
```

Is there way to apply modifiers such as `^` or `~` to the `:/` expression? I've tried the obvious syntax...

```
git show ':/Add widget^'
```

Which doesn't work:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument ':/widget^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

(And `git show ':/Add widget^' --` results in `fatal: bad revision ':/Add widget^'`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the anchored search, `'@^{/Add widget}^'` or do the substitution yourself with `$(git rev-parse :/Add\ widget)^`